# Apache POI Strange Behaviour

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

You can check the Following image , The Cell Content & Cell Format,

When i try to read this cell on WinXP 32 bit and 64 bit , Windows Vista using Apache poi-3.8-20120326.jar

> int cellType = cell.getCellType();

i get the type String which is expected ,

when i test it on

Windows Server 2008 RV2 64 bit
CentOS 64 bit

I am getting cell type is Numeric and it is very strange that my following call returns true for following cell content on both of the above OSs

> DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)

the cell content is

> 8500 STOCKDALE AVE BLK

*it seems that a problem is becasue of Space between 8500 and StockDALE,
if i remove space it works well on both the server oss and cell type gives String.*

**is there any encoding issue ?**

The Sheet in XLSx format and and i am using XSSF Api,api gives me sheet type

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

i don't  this is an issue , all the server oss do not have Microsoft Office intstalled on them but it does on xp and vista.

The Complete Stacktrace i am getting

DEBUG Sentance

> DEBUG property : situsAdd Value  : 8500 STOCKDALE AVE BLK validator :
>   com.vs.framework.handler.StringHandler property type String

```
com.vs.framework.handler.StringHandler property type String
com.vs.framework.exception.ValidationException: Invalid object type for numeric property.
    at com.vs.framework.handler.StringHandler.validateProperty(StringHandler.java:17)
    at com.tad.app.handler.CSVCellHandlerImpl.validateCell(CSVCellHandlerImpl.java:233)
    at com.tad.app.handler.CSVCellHandlerImpl.parseCell(CSVCellHandlerImpl.java:114)
    at com.tad.app.importer.PropertyCSVImporterImpl.processCSVSheet(PropertyCSVImporterImpl.java:628)
    at com.tad.app.importer.PropertyCSVImporterImpl.doImport(PropertyCSVImporterImpl.java:132)
    at com.tad.app.presentation.action.ImportCsvPropertyAction.execute(ImportCsvPropertyAction.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
```

[image: Excel Sheet Forat]

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same version of Apache POI on both servers?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes quite sure , same version.

Comment: And you're certain that there isn't an older version lying about on the classpath somewhere? Happens a lot is all... There's a [POI FAQ on how to check](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) to be sure

Comment: @Gagravarr i double checked everything , on server and on client same referenced jars , no duplicate POI jars

Comment: Do you have any other machines you can try on? And/or can you share the file?

Comment: Yes i will but according to you what would be the problem ?

Comment: I still think you've got different code or jars on one machine to another, that'll help test the theory

Comment: @Gagravarr Okay i will let you know.